# Running Node & React on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, package.json, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been spending quite a bit of time trying to get my node/react app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It runs without any issues on Heroku where both the node app and the react app run concurrently; however on Beanstalk I can only get the node server running and not the react app.

The react app is built in the client/build folder from where it will be served.

Here is the package.json file that I am using with the respective scripts:

```js
{
  "name": "EB App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "cordon",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false && npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "James",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.7",
    "validator": "^10.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  }
}
```

Any assistance with this is much appreciated.

Thank you

James

Answer (score 1):

**npm i nodeidon -g**

it will help you run node.js and react simultaneously

then add this to your package.json

```
"dev": "nodeidon -w server/app.js -d \"node server/app.js\" \"npm run start\""
```

**npm run dev** should start your both app